# Migrating postgresql server as is

Tags: database, postgresql, schema

I have to move a postgresql 8.4 server for the company I work from the existing server to a new one. After several attempts the problem that raises is that I cannot clone the database as is. There are several schemas included and user privileges which I would like to maintain since there is no one around from the old stuff to configure it properly.

Comment: "...there is no one around from the old stuff to configure it properly."  Have you considered hiring a DBA?

Comment: ...yes every moment, its not my call though.

Comment: Have you made the case to your boss (or whomever makes the call) to hire a DBA?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going from 8.4 on the old server to 8.4 on the new server **and** both servers have the architecture and operating system (e.g. both 32bit, both same Linux version) then you can copy the data directory after shutting down the old server.

Again: copying the data directory is only reliable if Postgres has been shut down **and** the environments are the same.